# Html form not submiting with appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Render JS file(contains html) into my Main Html file and that Html Form cant submitting because of js.

I used code like:

```
loadHeaderFooter();

function loadHeaderFooter() {
   var js = document.createElement("script");
   js.type = "text/javascript";
   js.src = "http://bargains-online.com.au/ebay/ebay_2015/new-theme/js/header.js";
   document.body.appendChild(js);
}
```

this above function render the JS file and Append the Html Code also to my Main HTML file but because of `document.body.appendChild(js);`.

My below code is not working:

```
function submitForm() {
   $('#frmPage').submit();
}
```

Comment: Do u have any element with id "header"??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('submit', '#frmPage', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("submit your form");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like window.addEventListener('load', loadHeaderFooter) instead of direct function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .selected{
        background-color : green;
    }
    </style>
<script>




    function submitForm() {
        $('#frmPage').submit();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
    });

    $(window).load(function () {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "http://bargains-online.com.au/ebay/ebay_2015/new-theme/js/header.js";
        $("head").append(s);

    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmPage" action="make_td_with_class_unselectable.html">
    </form>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <button id="test" onclick="submitForm()">check</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, your answer is right for appending the HTML content to the body, but please read my question again, I am asking that once I have added this code (to append the HTML content to the body), I am not able to do the code for submitting the form (i.e. $(form).submit())

Comment: @vicky plz check now

Answer (score 0):

You should really use something like [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for what you're trying to do. This might fix your problem and results in better readable code.